# How to include a .launch file on a remote machine from a .launch file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include, network, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to write a launch file that automatically ssh's and launches turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch on my turtlebot from my computer.  I'm using Indigo.  I have something like this:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="machname" address="mybot" user="myuser"/>
  <include file="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch" machine="machname"/>
</launch>
```

as suggested in [this question.](http://answers.ros.org/question/41413/how-to-include-a-launch-file-on-a-remote-machine-from-a-launch-file/)  However, like the some of the commenters in that question, I'm getting a "unknown  attribute 'machine'" error.  What's the correct way to do this?  Thanks in advance for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227764/how-to-include-a-.launch-file-on-a-remote-machine-from-a-.launch-file?/) by [JKostas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26104/jkostas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From reading through the source for roslaunch, and from looking at the other posts on that question, I'm pretty sure the undocumented feature you're trying to use was removed in later versions of roslaunch.

Instead, you might want to try using the `default` atrribute to the maching tag, to make all nodes run on the remote machine:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="machname" address="mybot" user="myuser" default="true"/>
  <include file="/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JKostas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26104/jkostas/) on 2016-03-02**:
Thanks!! I had other issues trying to run the XML above, and decided to give up and use a keyboard macro (xdotool's "key" command + python + python's subprocess module). However, while the XML may not work perfectly, this answer is, in general, a great solution to this issue.  Thanks again!